# Using Pointer to Struct to read member Variables

Tags: c, pointers, structure, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct data{
    int i;
    struct data *p;
};

int main() {
    struct data *p=malloc(sizeof(struct data));

    //How do i use pointer to structure to read a integer in member variable i?

    scanf("%d",&p->i);    // I am advised to use this,Can you interpret this??
    scanf("%d",&(*p).i);  // Is this valid?
    scanf("%d",p->i);     // Why is this not valid since p is nothing but a pointer 
}
```

1. Interpret this  `&p->i`. Why this represents the address of the member variable i?
2. Is this  `scanf("%d",&(*p).i);` valid? Why?

Comment: Please don't type up code for the question on the fly. Do it offline first, compile it and then copy paste. Your code cannot be something you actually tried. It's ill-formed all around.

Comment: it was a typo i have edited

Comment: Note that the local variable `i` in `main()` is unused, and wholly unrelated to the structure member of the same name.

Comment: Also note that the arrow operator is vastly preferable to the ‘star-dot’ notation when you need more than one level. For example, `p->next->next` is far easier to type and read than the equivalent using stars and dots and parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

In your case

- `&p->i` is the same as `&(p->i)` because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).
- `&(*p).i` is the same as `&(p->i)`.

and they both produce a pointer to an integer, as required by the `scanf()` function argument based on the supplied conversion specifier.

However,

```
 scanf("%d",p->i);
```

is not valid, as `p->i` gives you an `int`, whereas, you need a pointer to integer.

Comment: Can you please explain why am i able to dereference (p->i)

Comment: @rimiro not sure I understand your question. :(

Comment: My question is why is  `&(p->i)` representing the address of the member var `i`.   What is confusing me is since p is a pointer then why `p->i` not a pointer to the member variable i.

Comment: @rimiro nope, the `->` only gives you the member, not a pointer to the member.

Comment: that was what i wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` expects a pointer to something, in order to *store* data according to the format you provide to the function.

```
scanf("%d",&p->i); // I am advised to use this,Can you interpret this??
```

`p->i` gives you the integer `i` from the structure pointed to by `p`.
`&p->i` gives the *address* of `i`, required by scanf.

```
scanf("%d",&(*p).i);  //Is this valid?
```

Yes, that's the same as above. `(*p).i` is `p->i`

```
scanf("%d",p->i);  //Why is this not valid since p is nothing but a pointer
```

`scanf` needs a pointer to store a "%d", meaning an integer ; though, here you give the value of `i`, not a pointer to `i`.